# Select date and time using calender

Tags: c#, webforms

Im trying to select a time and date, using the Calender component in C# (visual studio 2012), and I can't find how to handle the hours. What im trying to achive is that when the user select the date he can also select a time.

Comment: I think with the standard [calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) control this is not possible. Its intent is to select a date/range of dates but not a time. Of course you may use other components and/or jquery (eg [datetimePicker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) ) for your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Format of the DateTimePicker to Custom, and then you can use a custom format that allows you to include hours-minutes as well:

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm";
```

You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more custom date and time formats.

Comment: are you sure this works in webForms? [calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class does not have format nor customFormat